# Error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'" using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm running this portion of code with different criteria, and it's giving me an `AttributeError`.

```
surl_list = []
for i in range(1, 21):
    surl = 'https://www.zillow.com/' + city +'rentals/' + str(i) + '_p/'
    surl_list.append(surl)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136"
}

sdata_list = []

for surl in surl_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(surl, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
    sdata = json.loads(
        soup.select_one("script[data-zrr-shared-data-key]")
        .contents[0]
        .strip("!<>-")
    )
    sdata_list += sdata["cat1"]["searchResults"]["listResults"]
```

I've tried to run just portions and it does run, but not straight through.

Comment: That's what happens when `soup.select_one` can't find any elements to select. You could either test that the element exists or catch the error - then do whatever error processing you think should happen.

Comment: As for "jamming in the loop", the traceback message should show you which line failed.

Comment: soup.select_one("script[data-zrr-shared-data-key]") is where its saying the error is.

Comment: the loop jamming is just my theory

Comment: don't posit theories: you control this code, test them. If you can't, omit them, if you confirm them, that's clues for debugging.

Comment: Inside the for loop, you could add a try/except block that catches the exception. In that case, print `soup.status_code` (it should be in the 200s for a successful post) and either print or save soup.text so you can see what you actually received from the server. It could be a bad url (maybe city doensn't have rentals) or maybe too many requests in a row (then you'll want to add sleeps and try again).